# How to combine CountVectorizer and LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I want to make NeuralNetwork with Keras that will classify my text data. I have 6 labels.
I'm vectorising the data with Sklearn's CountVectrorizer.

```
#my data
features = df[['content']]
results = df[['label']]
results = to_categorical(results)
    
# CountVectorizer
transformerVectoriser = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('vector word', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 2), max_features = 3500, stop_words = 'english'), 'content')],
                                          remainder='passthrough') # Default is to drop untransformed columns

features = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(features)

Features shape and type: (1600000, 3512) <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
Results shape and type: (1600000, 5) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

This is my model:

```
# CREATING THE MODEL
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=5, input_shape = (features.shape[1],1), return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
```

Fitting the model:

```
opt = SGD(lr = 0.001, momentum = 0.01)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta = 0.02, patience = 75, verbose=1, mode='auto')
history = model.fit(features, results, validation_split = 0.20, shuffle = True, class_weight = class_weight, epochs = 500, batch_size=1612, verbose=2, callbacks=[es])

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=512)
print(history.history.keys())
print(score)
print('Test loss:', score[0],  'Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

I'm getting the error when I want to fit the data:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1600000, 3512)
```

I know that I'm getting the error because of the bad data shape, but I do not know why should I set specific data shape, what data shape, and how to set that data shape.
When I want to make NN with only dense layers, I do not need to set shape.
Can you tell me more about this?

Comment: You are using an LSTM layer as your first layer. An LSTM expects a [batch size, time steps, features] sized 3D tensor. But you have a [batch size, featuers] 2D tensor.

Comment: can you tell me how should my code look like?